# Simple sufficient statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Given a sample $\{X_1, ..., X_n \}$ with the following pdf

$$ f(x; \theta) = \begin{cases} 2\theta^{-2} x, & \mbox{for } 0 \leq x \leq \theta \\ 0, & \mbox{otherwise }  \end{cases}$$

find a simple sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

---

My idea is to use Fisher-Neyman theorem for sufficient statistic.

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i; \theta) = (2\theta^{-2})^n \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot \mathbb I (0 \leq x_{(1)} \leq x_{(n)} \leq \theta )$$

Therefore, $T(x) =(\prod x_i, x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})^T$

However, the answer according to the authors of this exercise is just $ x_{(n)}$. Who is mistaken?

Comment: Both are sufficient statistics. But $x_{(n)}$ is minimal sufficient unlike your $T(x)$.

Comment: In the product, separate the terms that depend on $\theta$ from those that do not (and thus act as mere multiplicative _constants_).